# When I save form data on a Joomla site to the database, Joomla logs me out

Tags: php, joomla

Sorry for my English,

I have a problem with my Joomla site. I am trying to make a Joomla-based warranty registration system. Recently, I was able to turn on the possibility of registering new users and logging them in. Only registered / logged in users will be able to register the warranty.

Data from the guarantee registration form are to be saved in the database.

However, when I try to register the guarantee with a logged-in user, the website logs me out by itself and nothing is saved to the database.

Why is this happening and what can I do to improve the operation of the website?

https://flaex-elektronarzedzia.pl/gwarancje2/

Regards Adrian

Comment: https://flex-elektronarzedzia.pl/gwarancje2/ - right URL

Comment: Please never add question details as a comment under the question.  You may [edit] your question as many times as you like, whenever you like.  Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask all of your Joomla questions there.